# How to set targets in prometheus kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I am trying to setup Prometheus for my Kubernetes cluster. I am using https://github.com/coreos/kube-prometheus . I am using `default` namespace only. When I apply resources from `manifests` (https://github.com/coreos/kube-prometheus/tree/master/manifests) folder, It creates resources but in targets, it doesn't show my pod service.

I am new to Kubernetes so I need help with this. How do I configure my pod to show up in Prometheus targets? 
I tried https://github.com/coreos/kube-prometheus#quickstart

Answer (score 5):

For better manageability use [Prometheus Operator](https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator).

You need to define `ServiceMonitor` or `PodMonitor`

`ServiceMonitor` which declaratively specifies how groups of services should be monitored. The Operator automatically generates Prometheus scrape configuration based on the definition and the targets will have the  IPs of all the pods behind the service.

`PodMonitor`, which declaratively specifies how groups of pods should be monitored. The Operator automatically generates Prometheus scrape configuration based on the definition and targets will have the Pod IP

Refer to the examples [here](https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/tree/master/example/user-guides/getting-started)

Comment: Could you tell me how to do it with kube-prometheus ?

Comment: It's same check here https://github.com/coreos/kube-prometheus/tree/master/examples/example-app

Comment: So let's say I have 10 pods. Do I need to add separate service monitors for all of them?

Comment: For both scenarios. So the question is not for only service monitors, but for all files in examples folder.

Comment: At least in my experience separate files need to be created for different application